# Google translator API Not working in mac Mozila firefox

Tags: php, firefox, multilingual, google-translate

I am using Google Translator. It working Properly in all browser for all windows. But not working on MAC Mozilla firefox. And it working on MAC Safari and Chrome.
Here is my code

```
<div id="google_translate_element" ></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                    pageLanguage: 'en', 
                    includedLanguages: 'en,fr,hi',
                    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL,
                    autoDisplay: false,
                    multilanguagePage: true
                }, 
                'google_translate_element');
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Any Suggestion are welcome. 
Thanks..